# UIView opaque property is ignored when implementing drawRect:

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a UIView subclass that overrides drawRect: to achieve various effects (gradient background, rounded corners with different radii, etc). When I profile the app and enable color blended layers in the simulator/instruments, instances of this class are never green, even if it is just drawing a solid gradient and has the opaque property set to YES. Is there something special you have to do in drawRect: in order for that property to be respected?

Comment: Maybe check that the `alpha` value is 1.0?

Comment: Is the background color of the UIView an opaque color (alpha of 1)?

Answer (score 0):

May be your should set the "opaque" property to NO , as Apple Doc say :

> An opaque view is expected to fill its bounds with entirely opaque content—that is, the content should have an alpha value of 1.0. If the view is opaque and either does not fill its bounds or contains wholly or partially transparent content, the results are unpredictable. You should always set the value of this property to NO if the view is fully or partially transparent.

So in the drawRect method , if you draw some opaque layer , you should make sure that the the view's opaque property's value set to NO.

[UIView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)